# recordmydesktop file location

Tags: recordmydesktop

I have recorded a video with recordMyDesktop, but forgot to specify filename with save as dialog.

Documetnation at http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/manpage.php
tells that:

> recordMyDesktop produces a file(default out.ogv) that contains a video
> and audio recording of a linux desktop session.

Its not in last used folder /home/username/Videos

Does anyone know where default file out.ogv is saved if you do not specify a name in save as dialog recordMyDesktop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't specify a subdirectory the file chooser defaults to your user's home directory, which is where your file manager defaults to.

Click on the file manager (the folder icon on your launcher) and you should find out.ogv sitting in that directory.

Comment: copy from cmd line

Comment: nikola@nikola-MS-7376:~$ ls | grep out

Comment: output.pdf nikola@nikola-MS-7376:~$

Comment: working directory is /tmp

Comment: nikola@nikola-MS-7376:/tmp$ sudo ls -R | grep out
img.out
nikola@nikola-MS-7376:/tmp$ 
and that is output

Comment: i will just make a new recording

Answer (score 0):

1. Wait for the processing to finish
2. Click on Save As
3. The name of the file and directory is the location where the recording is saved
4. If there was a previous recording "out.ogv" then the new recodring will be something like out-1.ogv unless overwrite option was chosen in the same directory.